# Verifying Salt from Database

Tags: php, html

Im building a login/register project in school(beginner) and I have got a little stuck. I managed to has/salt my users when they register. But when I want to verify their login info with the hashes/salt I cant manage to pull it off it seems.

My register code is:

```
 $localhost="host";
 $user="user";
 $password="password";
 $database="database";
 $email =$_POST['email'];
 $passwords =$_POST['passwords'];

 $conn =new mysqli($localhost, $user, $password, $database);
 $error =$conn->connect_error;
 if($error){
    $code = $conn->connect_errno;
    die("Error: ($code) $error");
  }

  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
  $passwordFromPost = $_POST['passwords'];
  $salt = password_hash($passwordFromPost, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
  $passwords = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['passwords']);


  $sql = "INSERT INTO Users (email, passwords, salt) 
  VALUES('$email','$passwords','$salt')";
  $result= $conn->query($sql);


  $conn->close();
```

I read a little about it on another post here and I think I should be able to decrypt the pw with `$passwordCorrect = password_verify("password", $hashPassword);`

but im not sure how  to implement it in a php code and make it verify the user.
Any tips on what I should do as next step?

Answer (score 0):

You're not really creating a salt, [it is included as part of the hash](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html), and you would verify the password using the [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function. You never *decrypt* a password with this function, you just verify the hash is correct.

This line, `$salt = password_hash($passwordFromPost, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`  doesn't actually create a salt - it creates a password hash.

You're correct that you would use the function like this:

```
$passwordCorrect = password_verify("password", $hashPassword);
```

If password is verified `$passwordCorrect` will be `true`. If not, it will be `false`:

```
if($passwordCorrect) {
    // allow login
} else {
    // do not allow login
}
```

In your code you can get rid of some lines and change to this:

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$passwordFromPost = $_POST['passwords'];
$password = password_hash($passwordFromPost, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Now all you have to do is store the password and the email with no other data.

Now, query the database:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = ?');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['email']);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Now the user's password is in the result array and can be compared to `$_POST['password']`.

If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

**In addition:** [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Thanks, What lines to you mean I should get rid of?

Comment: You don't need the line escaping the password @Hippimaster

Answer (score 0):

First use prepared statement, not real escape string in your query to get used to best practices from the beginning.

You should not store the password, only the hash of it. So change
`$salt = password_hash($passwordFromPost, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`
to
`$password = password_hash($passwordFromPost, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`

and only store email and hashed password. Then when checking login you select password where email = the provided email and use password_verify('password from login', 'password selected from db') the result will then be true if the password match.